# PUT and DELETE methods not working on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, appharbor, put

I am having a lot of trouble trying to run an ASP MVC4 application with webapi on ApplicationHarbor's servers. I simply can't invoke the PUT and DELETE http verbs. Did you had the same problem? How did you solved?

I already tryed these configurations:

```
<remove name="WebDAV" />
<add name="PUTVerbHandler" path="*" verb="PUT" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
<add name="DELETEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="DELETE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

But it didn't worked either.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following configuration for the IIS 7.5 (integrated app pool):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```